# JOGL - Low performence after calling glMapBuffer on large array buffer

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I've got a strange problem, I want to update array buffer which contains about half a million elements (vertices), so I call `glMapBuffer(...)`, do some operations on some elements and call `glUnmapBuffer(...)`, but since then my program slows down even though I do this operations once in awhile.
Here is the code

```
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertices[0]);

        ByteBuffer verticesByteBuffer = gl.glMapBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.GL_WRITE_ONLY);

        FloatBuffer verticesBuffer = verticesByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();

        for(int i=0;i<verticesToBeChanged.size();i++) {
            int vertexId = verticesToBeChanged.get(i);
            verticesBuffer.position(vertexId*8);
            verticesBuffer.put(vertices[vertexId].position.x);
            verticesBuffer.put(vertices[vertexId].position.y);
            verticesBuffer.put(vertices[vertexId].position.z);
        }
        gl.glUnmapBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

Am I doing something wrong or this is how it works for large data sets?
I can't use `glMapBufferRange(...)` method due to it doesn't exist in JOGL.

Comment: You are right about `glMapBufferRange (...)`. I suspect the problem is that you are trying to map a vertex buffer that is being used for drawing. GL has to insert some implicit synchronization to make sure that changes to this memory do not affect commands that have not completed yet. You could try double-buffering the VBO if you have no other way to invalidate (e.g. orphan) the buffer. This is all disussed [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming).

Comment: You should get rid of `glMapBuffer`, since it forces a cpu-gpu sync. If you cant, make it 3x bigger and write it as a ring-buffer, writing only in one part and rendering another one.

Answer (score 1):

glMapBufferRange exists in JOGL 2:
http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GL.html#glMapBufferRange(int,%20long,%20long,%20int)